# About SimpleXML's foreach

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

what's wrong here? I want load a list of 10 items, but they are the same. Why?

```
<?php 

$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

$name = $xml->item->title;

foreach($xml -> item as $item){
    echo "$name<br>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're not accessing the values inside the loop:

```
$name = $xml->item->title; // NOT THIS!
foreach($xml->item as $item){
    // access `$item` inside this loop
    echo $item->title . '<br/>';
    // echo "$name<br/>"; // you're accessing that item outside the loop
}
```

Additional question:

Just trim the title with the numbering:

```
$i = 1;
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://store.steampowered.com/feeds/weeklytopsellers.xml', null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
foreach($xml->item as $item){
    // $trimmed_title = ltrim($item->title, "#$i - ");
    $trimmed_title = str_replace("#$i - ", '', $item->title);
    echo $trimmed_title. '<br/>';
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Nice! It's work . Can u help me again? How to remove this : "  #1 - " , " #2 - " .... in the results.